# How to kill process if access is denied and the pid belongs to the System

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

I am trying to run my program in Java and get the message that the port is already in use, so my program is not executed. 
I have tried to open cmd as admin and then kill the process however I faced the message
 "access is denied"
 after that, I have tried to kill it using task manager, no success.
-> the next step I have downloaded process Explorer which was as the same as task manager and found that pid belongs to System and when I clicked kill process I got the same results 
"access is denied"
I have tried also ->Properties->security, but permissions button is not clickable. I also tried to restart my pc with no success. I also googled it and got answers but they were not suitable for my case. So, in this case, how can I fix it?

Comment: *What* process are you trying to terminate?

Comment: pid which is 4.

Comment: Which port are you using?

Comment: the port I am using is 80

Comment: Then read the answer to [PID 4 is using port 80](https://superuser.com/questions/352017/pid4-using-port-80) on Super User.